# Change HREF attribute for right click save as?

Tags: jquery, attributes, href

So I have this...

```
$(this).attr("href", "http://site.com/images/downloads/wp-" + $(this).parent().parent().attr("id") + "-1024x768.jpg");
```

The problem is that when I Right Click > Save Link As... it doesn't link to the proper image. I'm not sure if its possible to do this or not, but I would really appreciate it if someone could help me on this. Thanks!

Comment: If you check your html source, what does the href attribute contain after that line has been run? the right or the wrong thing?

Comment: jQuery doesn't rewrite the html though so the source code doesn't have the url. In fact when you mouse over the image the url in the status bar does not read as the one I set with jQuery. But when I click it takes me to the link specified by jQuery.

Comment: When is your code run? On $(document).ready() or sometime else? If you use Firebug (an add-on to firefox) you'll be able to watch the DOM changes made by jQuery real-time, including changes to href attributes.

Comment: yes my code is run on document ready. The issue is that it is changing the URL for left clicks. So if you left click, that url has been changed. However if you right click save link as, it doesn't save the jpg that jQuery changed the href too.

Comment: I sure hope that you're executing this in php before you execute it in JavaScript, or it won't work at all because php is executed on the server whereas JavaScript is executed on the browser.

Comment: I've edited the code to remove the PHP so it is not distracting. I have no choice over when php gets executed. Its executed serverside so it isn't rendered to the browser. However due to NDAs I can't include the actual URL. I have replaced the php with site.com :D

Answer (score 1):

Use a diagnostic tool like Firebug or the DOM Inspector to examine the attribute's actual, final value.

The simplest explanation for differing click and save behaviors is if an event is being intercepted. "Save as" uses the actual href value, whereas selecting the link otherwise can be intercepted (keyboard, mouse down and up, click) to set the location to something else.

Answer (score 0):

You might be setting this up in `$(document).ready()` but the fact that you're using `$(this)` points to your code being bound to the `onclick` event of the `<a>`. That would explain why hovering over the link does not show the changed href, the value doesn't get changed until the visitor clicks on the link.

Can you should the associated section of your `$(document).ready()` to confirm my suspicions?

If I'm correct, then the solution should be to change the href as part of your `ready()` handling, rather than binding to the onclick event at that time.

Comment: the $(this) could also be from a each()

Comment: @Paolo: Good point. However, he also says: 'In fact when you mouse over the image the url in the status bar does not read as the one I set with jQuery. But when I click it takes me to the link specified by jQuery.' ... Since changing the href in advance of the onclick should result in the correct URL in the status bar, based on that comment I still suspect he's binding the href change to the onclick event. But I'll be happy to be proven wrong after I see his ready() code.

Answer (score 0):

here's an idea... put the "real" location in the html generated by php

then add an extra attribute with the "fake" location, and then use jquery to switch them on pageload. This can work depending on the situation (ie. it won't ruin everything if the user has js disabled and it uses the "real" location)

this would solve your problem and keep the end result the same for almost all of your users :)